# c# / Excel: PrintOutEx(...) won't print multiple copies of a document

Tags: c#, excel, printing

This method works fine... just not if I want to print the same document multiple times in one job.

These are the param-description for PrintOutEx:

```
void PrintOutEx(
Object From,
Object To,
Object Copies,
Object Preview,
Object ActivePrinter,
Object PrintToFile,
Object Collate,
Object PrToFileName,
Object IgnorePrintAreas
)
```

The 'copies'-param does not work for me:

```
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (Excel._Worksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(ws.Name[0])) 
            {
                object copies = view.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(x => x.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == ws.Name.Trim()).First().Cells[1].Value;
                if (copies == null)
                    copies = 1;
                else
                    copies = int.Parse(copies.ToString());

                ws.PrintOutEx(1, 1, copies, false, dialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
```

If anybody could give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Check which value returned from this statement: `view.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(x => x.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == ws.Name.Trim()).First().Cells[1].Value`

Comment: yes it's an integer, after the 'Parse(' that is... (even the right one :) I checked ...